# ModalViewControllerに代わるものはなにか

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

下記のサイトのような画面を作成したく、参考にしながら進めていたのですがどーやらswift4にはmodalViewControllerというものがないようです。

どのようにすればこのような画面ができるのか教えていただきたいです。

[【Swift】UIPresentationControllerを使ってモーダルビューを表示する](https://qiita.com/wai21/items/9b40192eb3ee07375016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まだネーミングルールに対する「Swift感覚」が十分に育っていないようなので、ピンとこないかも知れませんが、`ModalViewController`には`UI`だとか`NS`だとか、Apple製フレームワークにありがちなアルファベット2文字(最近のフレームワークなら`MTL`とか、3文字になることもある)の接頭辞がついていませんよね?

(SwiftがFoundationフレームワークのクラスを移入するときには、`NS`を勝手に取っちゃうときもありますが、今回はそれとは関係ありません。)

`ModalViewController`はApple製(あるいはSwiftに組込)のクラスではなく、**引用先記事の著者さんが独自に定義された`UIViewController`のサブクラスです**。

※引用記事のコメントまでよく読むと、実はそのことだとわかる書き込みがあります。

著者の方もはっきり書いていませんから、本来はどうなるべきかよくわかりませんが、例えば、こんな空の定義だけでもコンパイルは通ります。

```
class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

ここからスタートして、あなたの意図するデザインとなるように、内容を追加していかれると良いだろうと思います。是非お試しください。

Comment: あ！なるほど！理解しました。任意のViewController の名前だけであったのですね。ありがとうございます。